# Python2.7 Tkinter package, scope and class structure

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am using Tkinter in Python 2.7 and am having trouble with my class structure. Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont

class Display():

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

        self._geom = '200x200+0+0'
        parent.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(parent.winfo_screenwidth(), parent.winfo_screenheight()))
        parent.overrideredirect(1)

        parent.title('My App')
        parent.configure(background='#000000')
        parent.displayFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica", size=150)

        self.messageString="Hello"
        self.message = tk.Message(self, text=self.messageString, bg="#000000", font=parent.displayFont, fg="#777777", justify="c")
        self.message.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")


def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    window = Display(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am receiving the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_oop.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "main_oop.py", line 26, in main
    window = Display(root)
  File "main_oop.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.message = tk.Message(self, text=self.messageString, bg="#000000", font=parent.displayFont, fg="#777777", justify="c")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2817, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'message', cnf, kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2081, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2059, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: Display instance has no attribute 'tk'
```

The code worked until I included the last four lines of the **init** method, beginning with the line that uses tkFont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to make the instance of `Display` the parent for another widget (`...tk.Message(self,...)`). Only tkinter widgets can be parents of other widgets, and `self` doesn't represent a widget.

In this specific case you must use `self.parent` as the first parameter:

```
self.message = tk.Message(self.parent, ...)
```

Comment: If I use tk.Message as part of a method then, as in 'def printMessage(self, messageString)', how do I write the next line 'self.message = tk.Message(self.parent, text=messageString, bg="#000000", font=parent.displayFont, fg="#777777", justify="c")' so that parent is recognized?